unicode-math: DeclareMathOperator with lowercase Greek letters
Using lualatex the following
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\pgammal}{p\gamma l}
\begin{document}
$\pgammal$
\end{document}

works as expected.
But after adding the line \usepackage{unicode-math}, the output is only "pl", the letter γ (Greek lower case gamma) is missing.
It seems to be a font problem. Since without unicode-math there is a suitable font available, I hope it should be possible to reactivate it. I don't want to globally exchange any fonts, I like them as they are.
In my search for a solution, I opened this question yesterday: Lower case greek letters in Unicode not working in lualatex
Also, this one looks related: lost symbols with unicode-math
But I'm still not sure what the preferred solution for this problem should be.

Give \DeclareMathOperator{\pgammal}{p\mbox{$\gamma$}\kern0.4pt l} a try. (Depending on the math font you use, \kern0.4pt may not be needed.)

When typesetting \operatorname{...}, LaTeX uses the main text font (upright). And you get
Missing character: There is no  (U+1D6FE) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!

Solution: use the math font.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareMathOperator{\pgammal}{p\mathnormal{\gamma}l}

\begin{document}

$\pgammal$

\end{document}



Is this thing about using the text font for \operatorname some LuaTeX thing? If I use newtxtext in pdfTeX, then \operatorname is most definitely not typeset using the text font.

@Gaussler If fonts are properly set, of course.
